# google sheet: Change Colum Colour Based on User edit

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where three users enters data into the columns. I want to color them (column) based on the user. Which user has edited/Add the data into the column. Based on user edit the color of the specific column should be shown. Currently, I can see that which user has edit the column
[image]

Comment: "Based on user edit the color of the specific column should be shown"
What column color would you like to see when *different* users edit the *same* column? Should this be the color of the user who last edited the column? Or first? Or have you set the columns to be protected so that each user only has access to their own columns?

Comment: At the moment user can access every column ! I want to show the colour based on last edited user

Comment: The thing is that the user is not something that you can always retrieve. Ise the user modifying the spreadsheet from your own domain?

Comment: Own domain means? with the same internet ip? yes

Comment: Would you be okay with an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) solution?

Comment: yeah sure! I am programmer too

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding the most obvious solution is to create an [edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedit) so you can recognize the person editing the sheet and color according.

```
function colorByUser(e){
  let user = e.user;
  let range = e.range;
  if(user){
    Logger.log(user);
    Logger.log(user.getEmail());
  }else{
    Logger.log("User not defined");
  }

  if(user.getEmail() == "<THE EMAIL YOU WANT TO COLOR RED>"){
    range.setBackground("red");
  }else{
    range.setBackground("blue");
  }
}
```

Something like this, but because getting the user may be tricky sometimes so don't use a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and go directly for [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable):

```
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("colorByUser")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

You may want to take a look at this in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser):

> The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets

#### Result

[image: Sample of result]